# Adding header information to an enum using a custom attribute in C#

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I am able to create and build my own attributes and use them from within an enum, but I am unable to use these attributes as header information to an enum.

For instance, consider the following enum:

```
    [EnumSize(0x30000)]
    public enum Memories
    { 
        [MemSize(0x10000)]
        [Description("Memory0")]
        Memory0Base = 0x00000,

        [MemSize(0x10000)]
        [Description("Memory1")]
        Memory1Base= 0x10000,

        [MemSize(0x10000)]
        [Description("Memory2")]
        Memory2Base= 0x20000
    }
```

Now, I have created both EnumSize and MemSize attributes in the following way:

```
public class EnumSizeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private int _value;
    public EnumSizeAttribute(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

And made it more "access friendly" (meaning I can do something like this: Memories.Memory2Base.MemSize() or Memories.EnumSize()):

```
public static string EnumSize<T>(this T value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    EnumSizeAttribute[] attributes = (EnumSizeAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumSizeAttribute), false);

    if (attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].EnumSize();
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

Now, although it generates no compilation error when using it as a header to my enum as here below, I am unable to get the EnumSize by doing "Memories.EnumSize()".

```
[EnumSize(0x30000)]
public enum Memories
{ 
 ...
}
```

Any tip on how to get it to work would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to fetch attributes on the type of `Memories`, not on any one of its members. How have you declared the `EnumSize` extension method in this case? That's very relevant.

Comment: What is error did you get? How did you declared the `AttributeUsage` for your attributes?

Comment: @canton7, I have declared MemSize and EnumSize in the exact same way, which is obviously wrong by the sound of it :-)

Comment: Indeed! `MemSize` is also completely irrelevant -- just focus on `EnumSize`. @JohnathanBarclay posted a good answer, see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Memories` is a type not a field, so you would need to do something like this:

```
public static string EnumSize<T>() where T : struct, Enum
{
    EnumSizeAttribute attribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<EnumSizeAttribute>();

    return attribute?.Value.ToString();
}
```

And use as follows:

```
string size = EnumSize<Memories>();
```

You won't be able to call this as an extension method like you have with `MemSize` though.

The only way to do that would be to extend `Type`, for example:

```
public static string EnumSize(this Type type)
{
    EnumSizeAttribute attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<EnumSizeAttribute>();

    return attribute?.Value.ToString();
}

string size = Memories.EnumSize();
```

But that would be available to use with **all** types, not just enums, which is probably not what you want.

Of course you could throw an exception if it is used incorrectly:

```
public static string EnumSize(this Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumSize only applies to enums");
    }

    EnumSizeAttribute attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<EnumSizeAttribute>();

    return attribute?.Value.ToString();
}
```

But I would probably stick to the first example.

Comment: Thanks, I like your suggestions, I will give it a go!